# Deploying Helm Charts to a Kubernetes server from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to be able to automate deployments to my Kubernetes cluster using Helm charts executed by Jenkins (as part of the build cycle). The Jenkins machine is on a separate network to the Kubernetes cluster (rather than part of it as documented in numerous blogs).

I have a chart repo hosted inside a private GitHub account. I followed the process here: https://hackernoon.com/using-a-private-github-repo-as-helm-chart-repo-https-access-95629b2af27c  and was able to add it as a repo in Helm on an Azure server using a command of the format:

```
helm repo add sample 'https://MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN@raw.githubusercontent.com/kmzfs/helm-repo-in-github/master/'
```

I've been trying to get the ElasticBox Kubernetes CI/CD (v1.3) plugin inside Jenkins to connect to this chart repo, but whenever I press "Test Connection", I get a 400 Bad Request error. I have tried to enter the details in a variety of ways:

1. Using the same format (and token) as above and no credentials
2. Using the private token (same as in the query above) in the credentials, and the url of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kmzfs/helm-repo-in-github/master/
3. Using my username and password in the credentials, and the url of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kmzfs/helm-repo-in-github/master/

I have this plugin to connect to the Kubernetes Cloud and it can connect to the repository at https://github.com/helm/charts and deploy a RabbitMQ container.

Is it possible to get this plugin to connect to a private Github repository as a chart repository, and if so, how do I go about doing so?

If not, is there an alternative means of deploying Helm charts (in a private repo) from Jenkins? I couldn't find any other plugins that used Helm.

Thanks
Duncan

Comment: That 400 is likely coming from github. try curl -v https://MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN@raw.githubusercontent.com/kmzfs/helm-repo-in-github/master/' and see if it also returns a 400.

Comment: I get a 400 error if I do 'curl -v 'https://<myToken>@raw.githubusercontent.com/kmzfs/repo/'
', but if I use the full path and include 'index.yaml' in the path then I get the content of the yaml file. I assume this is why I was able to add the Helm repo from the commandline.

Comment: So if you use that full path with index.yaml when adding the repo to helm, does that work?

Comment: I can add the repo to helm directly, using the correct URL.  The problem is that I cannot add the repo to the ElasticBox Kubernetes CI/CD (v1.3) plugin using any variant of the URL (including with index.yaml). I have successfully added an open Helm repo to this plugin (no need for index.yaml in that case).

Answer (score 8):

What we use in our CI is completely skip anyfunky Jenkins plugins and just go for the native tooling. We bake kubectl/helm into the jenkins/worker image provide credentials to them so they can speak to the cluster and then take the private Helm chart not from published charts, but directly from private git repo holding that chart. And then we simply run `helm` against this localy cloned chart with a usual script step.

Example of kube config part defining the ca cert (related to comment below):

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <base64 ca cert>
    server: https://cluster_api_url
  name: mycluster
```

Comment: I started down that road, but I had certificate issues trying to connect into the Kubernetes cluster (either "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" or, if I use --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true then "Unable to connect to the server: EOF"). This is with the same Jenkins user that the plugin can hook up with. I'll have to do some more research into the certificate issues.

Comment: you should have CA data for the connection in the `.kube/config` to solve this - it should be CA cert used to create the certificate used by apiserver. example added in the answer above

Comment: I tried to use the kubeconfig file for the cluster as created by kubeadm, but that wouldn't work from outside the cluster because the server was specified using an internal IP rather than a URL.
I then created a new service account and followed this guide to creating a new set of certificates: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/#openssl
I left the apiserver arguments alone and used this token to authenticate into the server from the Jenkins plugin, but it won't work from outside the cluster through kubectl. Changing the apiserver args just breaks kubectl!

Comment: Should I be applying the process described here? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/ All these different certificates are why I went down the plugin route in the first place!

Comment: This sounds like something I would like to do, I basically want to have the helm command working. Do you have some examples on how you set that up? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on an open source project called [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) which is a proposed sub project of the Jenkins foundation aimed at automating CI/CD on Kubernetes using Jenkins and GitOps for promotion.

We worked around some of the issues you've been having by running the Jenkins pipelines inside the kubernetes cluster; so there's no need to authenticate with the kubernetes cluster - it just reuses the existing RBAC.

When you merge a change to the master branch, Jenkins X creates a new semantically versioned distribution of your app (pom.xml, jar, docker image, helm chart). The pipeline then automates the generation of Pull Requests to promote your application through all of the Environments via GitOps.

Here's [a demo of how to automate CI/CD with multiple environments on Kubernetes using GitOps](https://jenkins-x.io/demos/devoxx-uk-2018/) for promotion between environments and Preview Environments on Pull Requests - using Spring Boot and nodejs apps (but we support many languages + frameworks).

Comment: that link gives a 404